# Generate timestamp with milliseconds in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can anybody please advise on how to generate the following type of datetime stamp in Node?

```
2019-02-20T10:05:00.120000Z
```

In short, date time with milliseconds.

Many thanks.

Comment: I am confusing. are you expected to get miliseconds `1550657100120` or iso string `2019-02-20T10:05:00.120000Z` from date object

Comment: Either you mean milliseconds `[...].120Z` or microeconds `[...].120000Z`. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Date#toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/toISOString)

> The toISOString() method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ or ±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ, respectively). The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

```js
const res = (new Date()).toISOString();

console.log(res); // i.e 2019-03-05T10:15:15.080Z
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const now = (unit) => {

  const hrTime = process.hrtime();

  switch (unit) {

    case 'milli':
      return hrTime[0] * 1000 + hrTime[1] / 1000000;

    case 'micro':
      return hrTime[0] * 1000000 + hrTime[1] / 1000;

    case 'nano':
      return hrTime[0] * 1000000000 + hrTime[1];

    default:
      return hrTime[0] * 1000000000 + hrTime[1];
  }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new Date("2019-02-20T10:05:00.120000").getTime()
```

Answer (score 1):

new Date() already returns an ISO formatted date

```js
console.log(new Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date][1])

see this link they speak about toLocalDateString() function i think it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) like that :

> 2019-03-05T10:27:43.113Z

```js
console.log((new Date()).toISOString());
```

### Date.prototype.toISOString() [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

> The `toISOString()` method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` or `±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, respectively). The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

### Also you can do :

```
if (!Date.prototype.toISOString) {
  (function() {

    function pad(number) {
      if (number < 10) {
        return '0' + number;
      }
      return number;
    }

    Date.prototype.toISOString = function() {
      return this.getUTCFullYear() +
        '-' + pad(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) +
        '-' + pad(this.getUTCDate()) +
        'T' + pad(this.getUTCHours()) +
        ':' + pad(this.getUTCMinutes()) +
        ':' + pad(this.getUTCSeconds()) +
        '.' + (this.getUTCMilliseconds() / 1000).toFixed(3).slice(2, 5) +
        'Z';
    };

  }());
}
```